# Complex Demodulation (CDM) and Fixed Frequency Complex Demodulation (FFCDM)

Tags: algorithms, discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum

I do not quite understand the difference between the CDM and FFCDM.
How can I implement CDM in a program?

Comment: Why do you refer to them as "CDM" and "FFCDM", as if they are special algorithms or something?  When I googled those acronyms the top four hits were your question.  By "complex demodulation" I assume you are referring to quadrature downconversion.  Is that right?

Comment: Where did you find or hear these terms?

Comment: Actually I follow the paper in Ann Biomed Eng. 2006 Feb;34(2):326-38. Epub 2006 Feb 7.
A high resolution approach to estimating time-frequency spectra and their amplitudes.
Wang H, Siu K, Ju K, Chon KH.

Comment: Sounds like some domain-specific nomenclature that I'm not sure how to parse. Perhaps provide a more pointed question on what they're suggesting and what you're not getting.

Comment: Hi All,Apology for my explanation. I didn't clarify well.

Comment: Hi All,Apology for my explanation. I didn't clarify well.The goal of the paper 
is to zoom into a certain frequency BW of the time varying signal and analyse 
the spectrum. It is called Varible Frequency Complex Demodulation(VFCDM). 
VFCDM has three steps.(1)Design low pass filer according to the sampling freq 
and the desired cutoff freq, then do FFCDM to see the dominant freq as the following 
link "http://www.numerix-dsp.com/zoomfft.html".

Comment: Then(2)Decompose the signal into 
sinusoidal modulations
via the CDM.Then use the Hilbert transform to see the instantaneous 
frequencies, based on the phase, and the instantaneous amplitudesof each 
sinusoidal
modulation component.(3) VFCDM is based on the information from 
the first two steps, design another narrower BW LPF and extract more refined 
amplitude and phase information
via step 2. My problem is I can implement step 1.
I don't know how to implement "Decomposing the signal into sinusoidal modulations via the CDM." 
in step 2.Can somebody help to explain?

Comment: I am not familiar with stack exchange and don't know how to post long question.The editor didn't allow me for long text.Thanks Thomas

Comment: @thomas: Press the "edit" link under the question and add details to your question.  Then the comments can be removed